# Using .htaccess to redirect example.(us|es) to sub domain (us|es).example.com

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I recently purchased a new domain for my site and I want to redirect anyone who visits using an old domain to the new one.

For instance, if they went to either of these:

```
http://www.example.com -- NOT REDIRECT 
http://example.com -- NOT REDIRECT 


http://www.example.us --> http://us.example.com -- REDIRECT
http://www.example.es --> http://es.example.com -- REDIRECT
http://example.us --> http://us.example.com -- REDIRECT
http://example.es --> http://es.example.com -- REDIRECT
```

How would you do this simple .us|.es -> sub domain redirect with a .htaccess file? Any rule should apply to all URLs .

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example.us$ 
RewriteRule (.*) http://us.example.com [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example.es$ 
RewriteRule (.*) http://es.example.com [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this solution

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^ example\.us$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.us$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/us\.example\.com" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.es$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.es$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/es\.epys\.com" [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example.(us|es)$ 
RewriteRule (.*) http://%1.example.com [L,R=301]
```

Just like `$1` refers to pairs of brackets in the RewriteRule line, the `%1` refers to those in the RewriteCond